# How to analyze proportions data: Does the proportion of spent time in option A differ from the proportion of time spent in option B?

Tags: anova, proportion, sas

My research question is whether sheep prefer lying down on straw bedding (option A) or on a new type of bedding (option B). If sheep spent more time lying down on one option, we will say they have a preference for this bedding.

I have the data set up with two rows per sheep per day, one row for the proportion of time spent lying on each bedding type. For example:

| Sheep | Day | Bedding Type | Proportion of Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | OptionA | 0.72 |
| 1 | 1 | OptionB | 0.28 |
| 1 | 2 | OptionA | 0.66 |
| 1 | 2 | OptionB | 0.34 |

I am analyzing this in SAS using Proc MIXED. My model is Time = *u* + bedding type + sheep + *e*, with day as repeated measure (subject = sheep) and random effect of sheep.

However, I realize that two rows for every day are related - they always add up to 1 since it is proportions data.

**Specific Questions:**

1. Do I need to add something in to account for the relatedness (?) of the two observations per day?
2. Is using a general linear mixed model the appropriate way to analyze this? Would something like a paired t test or a Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test be more appropriate?
   **Edit:** My concern with using an ANOVA is that the two "observations" per day are **not** independent, and independence is one of the assumptions of ANOVA.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To answer your second question requires more information.  What is the experimental design?  Among other things, should we concerned about flocking behavior that might create a dependence among which bedding the animals choose?  How is the "proportion of time" measured?

Comment: 1) It was a pilot study, and I haven't found a term to describe what experimental design would fit. We tested one herd and gave them twice the normal space (half with bedding A, half with bedding B). They had an adaptation period of 5 days, and then we collected data for 6 days (bedding A on one side for 3 days, then switched to the other on the next 3 days).

Comment: 2) Yes, flocking/social behaviour is a limitation to this experiment. Ideally we would replicate this with new sheep. 3) The proportion of time was calculated from the time spent lying down in option A divided by the total time lying down that day (eg 7.2 hours in option A divided by 10 hours total)

Comment: Thank you BruceET. What type of test would that be called? // Yes, all days are of equal importance, but I am not interested in looking at whether day 1 differed from day 3. There is variation within and among individuals for how long they spend lying down each day. However, if I use proportions of time, then the variation in total daily lying time isn't considered.

Comment: What about looking to see if (and by how much) the proportion of time with new type (Option B) exceeds 50%? Simply a one-sample t test,  if data are normal. Maybe Wilcoxon SR, if not.// What concerns me is whether all Days are of equal importance.  Do sheep spend about the same amount of time being lazy every day?

Comment: Great! I will read up on those two. I have an additional question if you don't mind: If I used the lying time (min/day) instead of proportions, would I still have the issue that these are not independent? I think the answer is yes, I would still have the issue.

Comment: I agree:  Fundamentally, each day sheep vote either for A or B. With five or six votes out of six for straw, the preference for straw seems clear. See the comment about the sign test at the end of my Experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment (using R):

```
set.seed(2021)
x.b = rbeta(6, 5,9)  # fictitious data
stripchart(x.b)
```

[image]

```
t.test(x.b, mu=.5, alt="less")

        One Sample t-test

data:  x.b
t = -3.7488, df = 5, p-value = 0.006655
alternative hypothesis: 
 true mean is less than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
      -Inf 0.4616541
sample estimates:
mean of x 
0.4170871 

wilcox.test(x.b, mu=.5, alt="less")

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  x.b
V = 1, p-value = 0.03125
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location is less than 0.5
```

Comments: It is not obvious (to me anyhow) that the proportions should be normally distributed,
so it may be best to use the Wilcoxon signed-rank test. However, with only six days the Wilcoxon
test will have poor power. For my fake data
the Wilcoxon test does show that percentages
are significantly smaller than half.

Comment: Thank you for setting up an example! I am actually using SAS, so I've found coding to check the distribution. My data look normally distributed, based on the Q-Q plots, histogram and Shapiro-Wilk statistic. I also do not have any outliers. So I gather this means I can use a paired t-test.

Comment: I am not sure if I am interpreting the sign test correctly. Does it mean that if I had one sheep with a visible preference, but all others showed no preference, the statistics would show a preference exists?

Comment: Sorry, my brief comment at the end about a sign test was badly worded and confusing. (I have deleted it.) If you toss a coin six times and get all Tails (or all the same face) then you can reject the null hypothesis that the coin is fair at the 5% level.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!